# Polarities when expressing currents in terms of node voltages

Tags: circuit-analysis, nodal-analysis

This question is specifically about node voltage method. In this example I subtracted the nodes (Vth - V1) / R2 in order to express the current over R2.

It seems to have worked out as my calculations matched the multisim simulation.

But this leaves me questioning:

Why not V1 - Vth instead? How does one to about choosing their polarities when expressing currents in terms of node voltages?

[image]

Comment: The arrow marked for the current through R2 is left to right. The corresponding current equation is \$(V1 - Vth)/R2\$; right ? Also, the +&- for Vth is not marked.  What was the rationale for choosing \$(Vth - V1) / R2\$ in the first place ?

Comment: There was no rationale. Simply an error. I must have been lucky because the answer turned out correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can pick either polarity.

You can pick different polarities at different nodes.

You, however, must sum to ZERO the currents either

- flowing INTO the node

or

- flowing OUT_OF the node.

Thus I'd write that ---- summing currents **INTO** the node --- as

0 = I2 + (V1 - Vth)/R2 - (K * I) + I

but I'd redefine I as [ - Vth/1]